# Подключение сторонних файлов в Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qtcreator, include

Можно ли подключить в Qt creator .h файлы,написанные на c++ в vs2015,и использовать их функционал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Только .h файлы включаются в .cpp файлы через #include, сам Creator тут не при чем.

Comment: А если шаблонный класс в хедере и без реализации в cpp?

Comment: @Nikita тогда все равно можно :-)